# html5 mode is reloading page angular js

Tags: angularjs, express

how can i change the path without reload page?

Without html5 mode it's working fine. I'm using html5 mode, With "a" tag it's working fine but through ng-click it's reloading the page.
in controller i'm using `$window.location.href` for change path, Server side i'm using node js.
I'm searching solution for few days but not got success.
please help me.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html ng-app="myApp">
      <head>
      <base href="/" />

      <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
    </script>
      <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-
      route.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div ng-view></div>

       <script src="myapp.js"></script>
       <script src="myctrl.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

myapp.js

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "pages/main.htm",
            controller: 'myCtrl'
        })
        .when("/items", {
            templateUrl : "pages/items.htm",
            controller: 'myCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            template : "<h1>Nothing</h1><p>Nothing has been selected</p>"
         });
     });
```

myctrl.js

```
     app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$window',function($scope,$window) {

        $scope.myFunc = function() {
          $window.location.href="/items"

        };
        $scope.homePage = function() {
          $window.location.href="/"

        };
    }]);
```

server.js

```
 var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser =  require("body-parser");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));
    app.listen(3000,()=>{
      console.log(`server is up on port ${3000}`);

      app.get('/items', function(req, res){
          res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
      });
    });
```

Comment: Use `$location.path('pathHere')` instead.

Comment: you solved my issue bro thank's alot, i was going to crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the $window service to move through application cause the calls will be out of angular's scope, instead try to use **state** from the *IStateService* you need to add *ui.router* module to you app.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$state',function($scope,$state) {

    $scope.myFunc = function() {
      $state.go('items');

    };
    $scope.homePage = function() {
       $state.go('home');

    };
}]);
```

then config your routes

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router"]);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

   $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false}).hashPrefix('!');

    // Redirect to 404 when route not found
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
      $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('not-found', null, {
          location: false
      });
    });

    $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl : "pages/main.htm",
        controller: 'myCtrl'
    })
    .state("/items", {
        url: "/items",
        templateUrl : "pages/items.htm",
        controller: 'myCtrl'
    })
    .state("not-found", {
        url: '/not-found',
        template : "<h1>Nothing</h1><p>Nothing has been selected</p>"
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, issue has been resolved the answer is $location.path('pathHere').